# Is there anyway to to load javascript files in Visual Force sequentially?

Tags: javascript

I'm encountering the problem where the browser console is complaining about undefined objects on my Visual Force, which I discovered to be caused by the JS files not loading in the desired order. The loadOnReady attribute of the includeScript component only splits the loading into two separate contexts, but I need more than that. Is there another way to handle this besides combining js files together?

Comment: You might get better answers on [so].

Comment: You can use a javascript module loader like requirejs which can load javascript files in a sequential order. check this 
 out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581611/load-files-in-specific-order-with-requirejs